# Griffon Ormlite plugin configuration not picking up environment settings

Tags: java, ormlite, griffon

For my griffon desktop client application I'm trying to write some tests involving OrmLite. I have configured OrmLite with a java configuration file using the [configuration section of the griffon-ormlite plugin guide](http://griffon-plugins.github.io/griffon-ormlite-plugin/#_configuration). What I'm trying to do is configure OrmLite to use a different (blank) database during testing. However the application is not picking up the test configuration and is instead loading the default setting.

Things to note:

- specifying the configuration in exactly the same way as in *src/main/resources/Ormlite.groovy* in the configuration guide (link above) will cause the plugin to complain about a missing "default.url" setting. So either the example is wrong (it may be outdated, but that's unlikely) or I'm missing something regarding the environments (are the configurations being transformed before they are being read? I have not found any documentation on this).
- The [application environment](http://griffon-framework.org/guide/2.8.0/#_overview_metadata_environment) enum, is correctly resulting in Environment.TEST during testing and Environment.DEVELOPMENT during a run.
- versions: griffon 2.9.1, griffon-ormlite 1.1.0

Here's the configuration file:

```
import java.util.Map;

import griffon.util.AbstractMapResourceBundle;

import static griffon.util.CollectionUtils.map;

public class Ormlite extends AbstractMapResourceBundle {
    @Override
    protected void initialize(Map<String, Object> entries) {
        map(entries)
            // the default database setting
            .e("database", map()
                .e("url", "jdbc:h2:internal")
            )
            .e("environments", map()
                .e("test", map()
                    // the database that should be used during testing, but is not being picked up
                    .e("database", map()
                        .e("url", "jdbc:h2:mem:internal-test")
                    )
                )
            );
    }
}
```

Any help is extremely appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid the problem lies in that class based ResourceBundles do not offer support for the `environments` block (or any other conditional block for that matter) just like the Groovy scripts do. We recently added this kind of support to Properties files (see https://github.com/griffon/griffon/issues/196); leaving us with the need to add the same for class based bundles.

If you can, switch to Groovy script configuration as a workaround, make sure to add `griffon-groovy` as a project dependency. this will add at least ~7M worth of dependencies.

I've filed https://github.com/griffon/griffon/issues/212 to keep track of this feature.

Comment: You may want to give it a try to the latest 2.10.0-SNAPSHOT (must build your own form source) to give this feature a try, the fix is in place now. Feedback welcome :-)

Comment: Thank you so much. This is a better answer than I could've dreamed of :D. I will try and give the snapshot a whirl and see if anything comes up.

Comment: It's working like a charm :). Thank you so much for your help.